# Filtering string for date

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a string that looks like this:

> "51403074 0001048713      1302130446 TOMTOM101  Order
>   51403074-3-278065518: ontvangen"

This string is filtered from a array that contains similar strings. This string contains some relevant data and some irrelevant data. The only part of the string that is relevant is:`1302130446`. This number represents a date and time (yy/mm/dd/hh/mm). Because this part is a date and time its not the same every time.

How can I filter this string so that I will have a string that only contains the relevant part.

Sorry still learning IOS dev.

Comment: You've got to define SOME algorithm (at a level you can explain with words) that allows you to figure out which set of characters it the date.  Clairvoyant computers have not yet been invented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the date string will always be the third word you could split the NSString into a word array as

```
NSString *myString = @"This is a test";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

and then access the third item in the array to get the string you wanted.

**EDIT (due to comment):** To be sure that you get the correct string from your word array you need a unique identifier for your string. It could be that 'TOMTOM101' always follows the date string or something thing else...

**EDIT 2 (due to need of example code)

```
NSUInteger counter = 0;
NSUInteger dateStringIndex = 0;
for(NSString *str in myWords) {
    counter ++;
    if([str isEqualToString:@"TOMTOM101"]) {
        dateStringIndex = counter - 1;

        //We now know which word is the date number, so we can stop looping.
        break;
    }
}
```

(not compiled code)

Comment: Unfortunately not always I also have strings that look like this: '"51402432 1000204732 4/40 1302130817 TOMTOM221  Order 51402432-2-477100605: gestart' So now it would be the 4th word.

Comment: so what defines which position the date and time string will be located at?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a option. TOMTOM comes always as next word after the date.

Comment: Also, in your code, you may want to think abt what specific thing 'uniquely' identifies the date and time string. This might also allow you to filter it out.

Comment: ok, if TOMTOM always comes after the date time, then first iterate through your original string and  find the location of TOMTOM, then go back one block - a block is the set of characters seperated by a 'space'... and retrieve.

Comment: @Philosophia ok, do you have a example code for me or a documentation on this subject?

Comment: Sorry, i dont have example code, but i wrote down the basic algorithm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24534/discussion-between-user1805901-and-philosophia)

Comment: Filip edited the code for you! go Filip! he put the algorithm I was talking abt in code.

Comment: One last question so now i would replace myWords with my original string?

Comment: @Philosophia I mean the part of the example code where it says for(NSString *str in myWords)

Comment: yeah and I am asking you, do you understand what 'myWords' is doing? :)

Comment: @Philosophia not realy :P Still have to learn a lot i guess ;)

Comment: so in Filip's example code, these are things happening:-

you are looking for the string = 'TOMTOM101' in your original string 'myWords'.

counter is updated with each block of string, seperated by a 'space'

Once you find the specified str = TOMTOM101, you reduce the counter value by 1 and store the position in dateStringIndex.

this variable gives you the starting position(index) of your date string, now you have to actually parse again and extract it, at the stored index (dateStringIndex). And then create a new variable - say Date and assign it the parsed value.

Comment: Well explained Philsophia! :) Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the relevant string is 10 characters in length.

If the position of this relevant string is fixed in your original string (comes right after TOMTOM),

then you can do something like this:-

iterate through the length of the original string, and look for a block that is = 'TOMTOM'

while iterating add a counter value for count, update it by 1, whenever you meet a 'space'....aka when you meet the first 'space', add a counter value, say count = 1, then when u meet the 2nd space, update count = 2.. and so on,

when you find TOMTOM, your counter will have a value, say =4, therefore you know date string is located after count is set = 3 and before count is set = 4.

while count = 3 do: extract 'relevant string from original string'. When u come across the next 'space', update count = 4, and hence stop extracting from original string.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is separate the original string with one-letter space.

```
NSString *whatever = @"51403074 0001048713 1302130446 TOMTOM101 Order 51403074-3-278065518: ontvangen"
NSString *mydatestring = [self NthString:whatever :@" " :2];

- (NSString *)NthString:(NSString *)source:(NSString *)part:(NSInteger)i {
if (i >= 0) {
    NSArray* components = [source componentsSeparatedByString:part];
    return [components objectAtIndex:i];
}
else {
    return @"";
}
}
```

Comment: Where does NthString stand for?

Comment: Cant i just substring with nsrange?

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to read a book to learn basics to start with.